# The report definition has an invalid target namespace

Tags: sql, reporting-services

The report definition has an invalid target namespace http://shcemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition which cannot be upgraded.
I have made some changes to a report file. uploaded the .rdl to GitHub for DBA folks to deploy in the stage.
They say they get this error when trying to upload in the report builder and replace the existing one.
We are unable to open and check the report definition of the rdlc file in stage server to compare what version is in there. Is there any roundabout for this?

Answer (score 0):

in the report project you can configure the target version of sql server you're deploying for
reportbuilder has a version it works with
you should get the rdl version the reportbuilder can edit,
set it as target in  your project, build the project/report and upload the generated file in built reports to github